# Remove object from array where sub-object matches a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm currently attempting to sort through some values based on a query string. I'm able to target each `target` individually in this loop but cannot seem to properly remove them from the array. How can I remove certain values that match on `target.target` from `targetList`?'

```
targetList.forEach(function(target, key) {
    var os = getParameterByName('os');

    if (os == "android") {
        if (target.target.includes(":IOS")) {
            targetList.splice(key, 1);
        }
    } else if (os == "ios") {
        if (target.target.includes(":ANDROID")) {
            targetList.splice(key, 1);
        }
    }

    if (target.target.includes(":IOS")) {
        target.target = schools[target.target.replace(":IOS", "").toLowerCase()] + " (iOS)" || target.target;
    }

    if (target.target.includes(":ANDROID")) {
        target.target = schools[target.target.replace(":ANDROID", "").toLowerCase()] + " (Android)" || target.target;
    }

});
```

`targetList` contains an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "target": "t1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        51.0,
        1483574400.0
      ],
      [
        54.0,
        1485561600.0
      ],
      [
        54.0,
        1485648000.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "t2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        56.0,
        1484265600.0
      ],
      [
        70.0,
        1484352000.0
      ],
      [
        71.0,
        1484438400.0
      ],
      [
        51.0,
        1484611200.0
      ]
    ]
  },
]
```

What I'm attempting to do is that where a target matches certain criteria `.includes()` I want to remove the entire containing object/array.

Comment: what does `getParameterByName()` do and return?

Comment: My bad, that function just returns the value of a query string. It's returning the proper value based on what I type in.

Comment: create a demo that reproduces problem, None of the conditions will work on the dummy data shown

Comment: Basically splice is not actually splicing out the values I'm telling it to. If the target of the JSON contains either `:IOS` or `:ANDROID` it should be dropping the entire object from the array, but it is not.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, but it looks like you might use array.filter for this: `targetList = targetList.filter(function(target){ return target.target !== YourCondition; });`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your code works just fine. I've created a snippet where I removed the extra processing, to show that what you have already does what you ask.

Is there a reason you're doing stuff to `target.target` once you've removed it from the array? Do you have a reference to the containing object somewhere else?

```js
var targetList = [
  {
    "target": "t1",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        51.0,
        1483574400.0
      ],
      [
        54.0,
        1485561600.0
      ],
      [
        54.0,
        1485648000.0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "t2",
    "datapoints": [
      [
        56.0,
        1484265600.0
      ],
      [
        70.0,
        1484352000.0
      ],
      [
        71.0,
        1484438400.0
      ],
      [
        51.0,
        1484611200.0
      ]
    ]
  },
];

targetList.forEach(function(target, key) {
  if (target.target.includes("t2")) {
    targetList.splice(key, 1);
  }


});
  
console.log(targetList);
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @Alnitak I disagree: I've created a runnable snippet that only contains the relevant parts, and demonstrates that the code provided, when truncated a bit, works as requested.

Comment: "spot the difference" answers aren't useful either.